# Domain name is not displayed in URL after redirection

Tags: domain-name-system, web-hosting, cname-record, magento

I have a domain on GoDaddy and have hosted a Magento project on it. I now purchased CloudWay and have migrated on their server. My issue is with URL, I created a subDomain `live.******.com` and set CNAME from CPanel.

On Firing, this URL my New Hosted page is getting launch but its URL does not remain `"live.******.com"` there it changes to **http://magento-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx.cloudwaysapps.com**/. 
I am not much aware and tried to search a lot but didn't find the proper solution. Might be I am too new for this.

**EDIT**

**CloudWays Console**
[image]

**DNS**
[image]

Comment: You need to set this within your cloudways account.

Comment: Can u please provide some more detail, I am newbie to such thing

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to set up an A NAME record as well:

https://support.cloudways.com/how-to-point-my-root-domain-to-my-new-cloudways-server/

And make sure domain mapping is set up correctly:

https://support.cloudways.com/how-do-i-take-my-website-live-from-cloudways/

And don't forget it takes some time for the new settings to propagate world-wide:

https://www.godaddy.com/help/what-factors-affect-dns-propagation-time-1746 
https://www.siteground.com/kb/what_is_dns_propagation_and_why_it_takes_so_long/

Comment: I tried these way but still something is going wrong.

Comment: And as I said.. Redirection is working fine.. just the problem is with URL that is being displayed.

Comment: Please bear in mind DNS propagation: https://www.siteground.com/kb/what_is_dns_propagation_and_why_it_takes_so_long/

Comment: I did these things two days before :)

Comment: You must have missed something, even browser cache perhaps. Perhaps take (censored) screenshots of your DNS, server and Cloudways settings so we can help backtrace your steps and find the missing link.

Comment: I just added images. It might help

Comment: Btw.. I missed to restart Server after whatever i did. Silly mistake:) but thanks JayMcTee.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer** - Just restart the Server

**Long Answer** -  Actually yes, the mistake was I didn't restarted my server after all kind of configurations. But, few things that one has to consider in setting up with CloudWays are,

- Check the A Record in Domain Registrar's Console. Make sure that it matches with the one that is displayed on Instance summary in Cloudways.
- Check CNAME provided, It should point to proper instance Name that is displayed in Domain Manager section.